# How to execute "grep" only in the folder you're in

Tags: command-line, grep

So say I'm in /home/folder1, which contains lots of .txt files. If I want to use `grep -r "xxx" ___`, how would I make the ___ mean that I only want the grep to command to look in the folder I'm in?

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `-r` (recursive) flag, and instead use a shell glob for the files you want to search:

```
grep 'xxx' *.txt
```

Comment: To clarify, I actually to check if the "xxx" is inside one of the files. Would this command still work
EDIT: I've checked, not all the files are .txt, should I just do *

Comment: @DrBracewell Use a glob that includes all the files you want to search. So for example, to search all .txt and .ini files, use `grep 'xxx' *.txt *.ini`. For more info about globbing, read this and the related links: [What is file globbing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30229465/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `./`? This explicitly means "**this** folder".

```
grep 'xxx' ./*
```

This will scan all of the files in the **current** folder for all occurrences of `xxx` inside each file.

And of course if you want all of the files in the **sub-directories** of the current directory to be scanned as well, then use:

```
grep -r 'xxx' ./*
```

And in fact if you are already in the directory of your choice (use `ls` and `pwd -P` to make sure), then it is truly redundant to use `./`. So this should also work in the same way and give you the same output:

```
grep -r 'xxx' *
```

Comment: Mentioning the current directory explicitly (`./`) shouldn’t make any difference in this case.

Comment: @benett Melebius means that there is effectively no difference between `*` and `./*`.